# C# Mongo Builders<T>.Filter lambda for an array field

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

How do I use lambda expressions in C# with Builders and lambda expressions to match against a field in an array of a class. Let me clarify.

Presently I have a document in mongo, and a C# class. I am using aggregation pipeline to match documents. I do this using a lambda expression for type safety and elegance reasons.

I have the follow code to add a filter.

```
    public RegularExpressionFilterSingle<T> AddFilter(
        Expression<Func<T, object>> FilterSpecification)
    {
        FilterDefinitions.Add(
            Builders<T>.Filter.
                Regex(
                    FilterSpecification, // e.g. x => x.Email
                    new BsonRegularExpression(Text,"i")));

        return this;
    }
```

The the following code will add a number of filters.

```
                RegularExpressionFilterSingle<User>
                RegExp = new RegularExpressionFilterSingle<User>
                    (new List<FilterDefinition<User>>(), Word.Trim()).
                        AddFilter(x => x.Email).
                        AddFilter(x => x.Title).
                        AddFilter(x => x.FirstName).
                        AddFilter(x => x.LastName);
```

This all works nicely the document structure at this stage is flat only fields. Now I have added a field which is list of a class, in C# this is.

```
    [BsonElement("product")]
    public List<UserProduct> Products { get; set; } = default;
```

So I want to add a filter which also matches against items in this array. My partially working attempt is as follows.

```
                RegularExpressionFilterSingle<User>
                RegExp = new RegularExpressionFilterSingle<User>
                    (new List<FilterDefinition<User>>(), Word.Trim()).
                        AddFilter(x => x.Email).
                        AddFilter(x => x.Title).
                        AddFilter(x => x.FirstName).
                        AddFilter(x => x.LastName).
                        AddFilter(x => x.Products[1].Name);
```

You will notice the addition of

```
AddFilter(x => x.Products[1].Name);
```

How do I search so that if any of the Products[...].Name matches not just the one at index 1?

I did come across this post ([Lambda Expression to filter a list of list of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811219/lambda-expression-to-filter-a-list-of-list-of-items)), but it didn't seem to answer my questions.

Many thanks

Comment: Since `products` is an array field, I think you need to use an [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) to match the array elements using regex.

Comment: Thanks @prasad, that makes allot of sense. Will take a look at the link you shared.

Comment: Essentially this is what I am looking to code in C#. db.getCollection('users').aggregate([{
     $match : { 
        "product" : { "$exists" : true } ,
        "product.name" : "A product name"
     }
 }])

Comment: Here are posts with similar issue: [Filter array elements with $regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704440/filter-array-elements-with-regex) _and_ [Regex inside array in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22909081/regex-inside-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: Thanks again @prasad , final step for me is to workout how to use the C# driver syntax to do this programatically..

Answer (score 1):

the mongo driver can't translate the member expression you need for the regex filter to work in a strongly-typed manner.

you'd have to create your own function that will take in a lambda and convert it to a dotted string path.

i've already created such a function for my mongodb library which you can find [here](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/29e36a34ef1922957f8a08ed42868334b5b500f9/MongoDB.Entities/Utilities/Prop.cs#L79)

with it you can simply do the following:

```cs
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter
    .Regex(Prop.Path<User>(u => u.Products[0].Name),
        "^something");
```

which will translate to the following filter if you do an aggregate query with it:

```
{
    "$match" : {
        "Products.Name" : /^something/
    }
}
```